# Maven parents and childs in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

In my maven project I have 1 main and 2 modules. It only compiles and runs when I add the two modules to the dependencies in the main pom.xml, otherwise I get compile errors that the reflections library etc is not found.

How can I solve this?

**powercontrol.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.nberlijn.powercontrol</groupId>
    <artifactId>powercontrol</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>log</module>
        <module>kernel</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.nberlijn.powercontrol</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.nberlijn.powercontrol</groupId>
            <artifactId>log</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**kernel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.nberlijn.powercontrol</groupId>
        <artifactId>powercontrol</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**log.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>nl.nberlijn.powercontrol</groupId>
        <artifactId>powercontrol</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>log</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details on the code inside each of your modules, it is hard to say why this is. However, by placing your two modules as dependencies in your parent POM, they and their transitive dependencies will be inherited by both child modules.

I think you should be able to resolve this by removing the dependencies from your parent POM, and adding a dependency to your `log` POM to depend on your `kernel` module.

Comment: Can it be the problem that in main (parent) I have a also java code? Should I make a new module for the (main/app) code? I'm just reading and guessing!

Comment: Your `packaging` for your parent module is `pom`. This means that it will not build a jar from your parent module, only for your child modules. So yes, any Java code should go in one of your child modules (or a new one if required)